# How to retrieve current style value with JS as a number and not a word?

Tags: javascript, getcomputedstyle

I use `getComputedStyle(element)[type]`, where element is my `<p>` tag and `type` is either `fontSize, lineHeight, letterSpacing, fontFamily` or `width`. For fontSize and width, I get numerical values, like 16px and 100%. Which is something I can work with, but for letterSpacing and lineHeight I get `normal` as a value. But I need it as a numerical value, so I can add and subtract it. I want to manipulate it using JS.

In my Stylesheet it looks like this:

```
:root {
  --font-size: 1rem;
  --line-height: inherit;
  --letter-spacing: 0rem;
  --font-type: inherit;
  --text-width: 100%;
}
```

There is the option to just manually write an array with the values I have already set, and work with that. But I still would have a problem with lineHeight, as it inherits it.

Here's an example:

```js
const target = document.getElementById("target");
console.log(getComputedStyle(target)["lineHeight"]);
```

```css
:root {
  --font-size: 1rem;
  --line-height: inherit;
  --letter-spacing: 0rem;
  --font-type: inherit;
  --text-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p id="target"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get `normal`, I don't think there's a way to get the actual numeric equivalent of that.

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Values):

> **`normal`**
>
> Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default value of roughly `1.2`, depending on the element's `font-family`.

So you could assume `normal` => `1.2` but it's not a reliable assumption.

Depending on what specifically you're doing [`getClientRects`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects) may be useful since it can tell you how tall the paragraph is. If you save its content and give it just a single character like `x` (then restore its content after measuring), that would tell you how tall in pixels a line in that paragraph is, all other things being equal:

```js
const target = document.getElementById("target");
console.log(getComputedStyle(target)["lineHeight"]);
console.log(target.getClientRects()[0].height);
```

```css
:root {
  --font-size: 1rem;
  --line-height: inherit;
  --letter-spacing: 0rem;
  --font-type: inherit;
  --text-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p id="target">x</p>
```

Whether that's useful will depend on what you're doing, though.